# How do use the Spree theme for Custom pages I create

Tags: spree

Is there a better way of using say the blue spree theme on other non spree pages?

I'm just going through and including the files that I can and adding the HTML I can't get from the includes into a master template. Would be nice if there was a better / easier way.

Answer (score 4):

After some digging I figured it out.

All you have to do is set your controller to inherit from the Spree::StoreController

so go into whatever controller you want to do this for and change this:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

To this:

```
class FooController < Spree::StoreController
  def index
  end
end
```